# solr how to do filter on html entity

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud, solrnet

I have used htmlStripCharater filter in index time analyzer so all the html character are getting decoded, example- `&reg;` will be indexed as ® I have done it because of some internal NLP things that we are doing , and  it is serving the purpose well.

The problem is occuring when I am trying to do execute the filter query .
Example I have a brand -
helloWorld®  . When filter query is getting executed like `brand%3AhelloWorld%C2%AE` solr again changing % to %25 .
So the query is actually going as `brand%253AhelloWorld%25C2%25AE` , And I am unable to get the data from solr.

Any idea how to solve this ?
I am using the old solr version 4.10 .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `DataImportHandler` you can use the [HTMLStripTransformer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HTMLStripTransformer).

Otherwise, you'll have to implement this client-side on your own. If your client is .NET you could use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=htmlagilitypack).

Comment: even if you use HTMLStripTransformer , its not going make any difference  . Because the issue is is with the query side .